# Incompatible library version: nokogiri.bundle requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew, libiconv

In an attempt to get mysql installed on my mac for a rails project I followed an online suggestion of installing homebrew and removing mac ports. This is where the problems began. The rails project won't build, I am getting this:

> > [rake --prereqs] rake aborted!
> >
> > dlopen(/Users/Parker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle, 9):
> >
> > Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
> >
> > Referenced from: /Users/Parker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
> >
> > Reason: Incompatible library version: nokogiri.bundle requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0
> >
> > /Users/Parker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
> >     /Users/Parker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
> >
> > ...

I've tried the suggest of running

> brew install libiconv

to which I receive the message:

> > Error: No available formula for libiconv
> >     Apple distributes libiconv with OS X, you can find it in /usr/lib.
> >     Some build scripts fail to detect it correctly, please check existing
> >     formulae for solutions.

I've also tried

> gem install nokogiri -- --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28 --with-xml2-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1

to which I receive:

> > ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
> >
> > ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
> >
> > /Users/Parker/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28 --with-xml2-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1
> >     Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK
> >
> > Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
> >
> > Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
> >
> > Running 'install' for libxml2 2.8.0... OK
> >
> > Activating libxml2 2.8.0 (from /Users/Parker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/libxml2/2.8.0)...
> >
> > Extracting libxslt-1.1.26.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/ports/libxslt/1.1.26... OK
> >
> > Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
> >
> > Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
> >
> > Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.26... OK
> >
> > Activating libxslt 1.1.26 (from /Users/Parker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/libxslt/1.1.26)...
> >
> > checking for libxml/parser.h... no
>
> >
>   -----
>   libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for 
>   help with installing dependencies.
>   -----
>
> > *** extconf.rb failed ***
> >     Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
> >     libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
> >     need configuration options.
> >
> > Provided configuration options:
> >         --with-opt-dir
> >         --without-opt-dir
> >         --with-opt-include
> >         --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
> >         --with-opt-lib
> >         --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
> >         --with-make-prog
> >         --without-make-prog
> >         --srcdir=.
> >         --curdir
> >         --ruby=/Users/Parker/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
> >         --with-zlib-dir
> >         --without-zlib-dir
> >         --with-zlib-include
> >         --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
> >         --with-zlib-lib
> >         --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
> >         --with-iconv-dir
> >         --without-iconv-dir
> >         --with-iconv-include
> >         --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
> >         --with-iconv-lib
> >         --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
> >         --with-xml2-dir
> >         --with-xml2-include
> >         --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
> >         --with-xml2-lib
> >         --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
> >         --with-xslt-dir
> >         --with-xslt-include
> >         --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
> >         --with-xslt-lib
> >         --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
> >         --with-libxslt-config
> >         --without-libxslt-config
> >         --with-pkg-config
> >         --without-pkg-config
> >         --with-libxml-2.0-config
> >         --without-libxml-2.0-config
> >         --with-libiconv-config
> >         --without-libiconv-config
> >
> > Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Parker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0 for inspection.
> >
> > Results logged to /Users/Parker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out

I have worked to resolve this issue for well over 8 hours. I have tried every link and every suggest google supplies me with. I am completely stumped. It seems to me I'm in over my head and have caused some environment issues. I realize more information is probably needed, but I don't know what to supply. Please let me know what other information would help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally found a combination of suggestions that resolved my issue:

> http://www.rqna.net/qna/swryr-bundle-install-stopped-at-nokogiri.html
>
> > brew tap homebrew/dupes

then:

> > brew install libiconv
> >
> > brew link --force libiconv

Apparently 'brew tap homebrew/dupes' allowed me to use the 'brew install libiconv' without an error, and from there the 'brew link --force libiconv' remedied the issue.